# Separate ThreeJS model and animation data

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, three.js

Is it possible to de-couple the animation data and model data in ThreeJS?

So that one could swap models, and keep the animation? I think this could be very powerful

The way I know how to do it in ThreeJS is having every animation one after the other packed inside a single model, which seems limited.

For example, in a game, you could change character model, instead of having each character model include the 'baked' (am I using the correct term?) animations. What If I want to change the animations, would I need to re-bake every single model? Sounds so counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation data could be made reusable under two conditions:

1. The mesh is the same, you could reuse the model/animations, and assign a different material/shader.
2. The models use skeletal animations, and the skeleton is the same across models.

If the animations or models are substantially different from each other, you probably would not be able to reuse the animation data.

Note that if the names of the animation KeyframeTracks match objects in your model's tree, it may simply work with any models that have the same-name nodes.

Also, unless there are a lot of animations, baking (yes, that is the correct term) might be a better idea. Baked animations can be more efficient than computing the skeleton.